# Reporting Status Results for Control Transfers

Tags: usb

Consider section 8.5.3.1 of [USB 2.0 specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/):

> Control write transfers return status information in the data phase of the Status stage transaction.

> For control writes, the host sends an IN token to the control pipe to initiate the Status stage. The function
>   responds with either a handshake or a zero-length data packet to indicate its current status.

In IN transactions handshake is done by host, not device!

Question is: how device can send handshake for an IN transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > In IN transactions handshake is done by host, not device!

I believe there is some misunderstanding.

Device sends NAK/STALL during handshake phase of IN transaction(control write) **if** there is no data packet during status stage.

**If** there is a data packet from function corresponding to the IN token, the function expects ACK handshake from host after sending the data packet.

Data packets during status stages are Zero Length Packets.

This is the illustration of scenario in the question:

[image: status stage of control write]

See also link in comments.

Comment: Do you know where it is written in USB spec that device may send handshake to IN token? Device may send handshake only for IN tokens, or for OUT tokens too? (it seems SETUP token must always have data phase, but again, it would be great to have a quote from USB spec in the answer...)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Your question has the quote from spec. "the host sends an IN token to the control pipe to initiate the Status stage. The function responds with either a handshake "

Comment: Device must send handshake to OUT token. For IN token, device may choose to send data packet with zero length or ACK handshake. This is what spec is saying which you quoted in your question.

Comment: What I mean is a general description how the exchange process is done, not things deduced from context. If I find the relevant quote, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml - Is this what you were asking? Please feel free to edit the answer which suits best to the question. Thanks :)